# Is there somewhere a procedure to manually calibrate the PID?

Tags: calibration, pid

I own a Balco rebranding of the Duplicator i3+ and after having replaced the plastic driving gearbox with a metallic one, it appears that for some reason the extrusion temperature became unstable and I suppose I should to re-calibrate the parameters of the PID.

However, I have been using this machine stand alone and I do not have a computer nearby nor the space to put one. And since it has a tactile screen, it won't show me the result of the gcode execution.

Does anyone know of a manual procedure to calibrate a PID in order to at least stop the temperature swings ?

Comment: It is unlikely that the driving gearbox influences PID values, since PID calibration is performed without the filament moving. Maybe some wires got loose or damaged. Maybe you touched the thermistor, most likely explanation. I would not worry with PID until everything else has been checked. You would likely waste time

Comment: Well, I found it unlikely too, but I tried to put the original plastic gearbox back to make sure, and the temperature got stable again with the default PID parameters. The only explanation I suspect, would be that it touches the cool block's dissipator and changes it's thermal properties.